# Counterexample for the invalidity of the following

Tags: examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Premise 1: $\quad \exists x \ [A(x) \lor B(x)]$

Premise 2:$\quad \exists x \ \lnot A(x)$

Conclusion: $\quad \exists x \ B(x)$

The argument is invalid, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Please consider using [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing mathematical text, in order to produce beautiful and very readable questions.

Answer (score 3):

Choose $A(0)$ to be true and $A(x)$ to be false for all $x\neq 0$ and $B(x)$ to be false for all $x$.